# Random Images Displayed In Slider

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, slider

I am using an image slider with 7 images. I have a folder in my ASP.NET Web Forms application called Slider with 50 images in it. Every time I refresh or visit the page I want the slider to be populated with 7 different images every time from the 50 images in the folder.

**ASPX**

```
<div class="slider">
                <div id="slider1">
                    <% Response.Write("<img src='" + chooseImage() + "' />");%>
                   <%-- <img border="0" src="Slider/B50.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/B51.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/C47.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/C43.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/E2.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/W5.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/M21.JPG" width="850" height="637" />--%>
                </div>
                <ul id="thumb"></ul>
                <div id='next' class="slider_next">
                    <img border="0" src="Images/next.png" width="57" height="57" alt="next image" /></div>
                <div id='prev' class="slider_prev">
                    <img border="0" src="Images/prev.png" width="57" height="57" alt="previous image" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Before I just had a direct path to 7 images in the folder but I want it to be randomized.

```
<% Response.Write("<img src='" + chooseImage() + "' />");%>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chooseImage();
        }
        public string chooseImage()
        {
            if (Session["img"] == null)
            {
                string imgPath;
                int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Slider/"), "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
                fileCount = fileCount + 1;
                imgPath = "Slider/" + RandomNumber(1, fileCount) + ".jpg";
                Session["img"] = imgPath;
                return imgPath;
            }
            else
                return Session["img"].ToString();
        }
        private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }
```

When I run the application no image is being displayed in the slider.

**Slider Folder**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getting the `imgPath`, you need to resolve the url to make it valid for the client. This can be done through the `Control.ResolveUrl` method:

```
imgPath = ResolveUrl("Slider/" + RandomNumber(1, fileCount) + ".jpg");
```

If the image source is invalid, no image will be displayed.

However, once you resolve the url, all images will probably be the same since you are caching the results to `Session["img"]`. In order to get randomized images every time, simply remove the `if` statement and the `else` body.

You should also change your

```
Random random = new Random();
```

local variable declaration to an instance variable or static variable, as discussed in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number).

**Edit**: you should probably rewrite your `chooseImage()` method to get any file within the directory "Slider". As it is currently, it will only return paths such as "Slider/1.jpg" and "Slider/2.jpg".

```
public string chooseImage()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Slider/"), "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    int fileCount = files.Length;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(files[RandomNumber(0, fileCount)]);
    return "Slider/" + fileName; // or return ResolveUrl("Slider/" + fileName);
}
```

Comment: my images are not being displayed still the folder is in the project and each image would have a path example "Slider/A2.jpg" so my path should be "Slider/" right?

Comment: Is the "Slider" folder on the root directory?

Comment: yes its in the solution explorer with all the other files it had no problem displaying them when I had a direct path to the image

Comment: my slider has a specific size how would I style this line "<% Response.Write("<img src='" + chooseImage() + "' />");%>" like give it a height and a width for the image

Comment: Just add the attributes to the img tag

Comment: Example: <% Response.Write("<img src='" + chooseImage() + "' border="0" width="1px"/>");%>

Comment: I get an error when I do this. The style is underlined and it says "; expected"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the quotes. You will need to use single quotes around attribute values. Example: <% Response.Write("<img src='" + chooseImage() + "' border='0' width='1px'/>");%>

Comment: Thanks just need to fix the random now because it keeps displaying the same image multiple times.